# Net Beans 8 and PHPUnit-Skeleton-Generator

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

This question is geared towards anyone using Net Beans 8, or any newer version, and PHPUnit. I'm a little confused by which direction to go in and am wondering if anyone who has already done this can point me in the best direction.

I have setup PHPUnit and PHPUnit-Skeleton-Generator in my Net Beans 8.2 installation. I ran the demo in their documents and everything works as it is supposed to.

The demo from the Net Beans document creates a simple calculator class to add two numbers. You use the @assert notation in block quotes above the class with two values to be added and the expected result. The PHPUnit-Skeleton-Generator reads each @assert and creates a test script using PHPUnit for testing. All works as planned.

My next step was to find other more complicated examples to learn from. In that research, I find that PHPUnit-Skeleton-Generator is deprecated and the assert methods are different in PHPUnit.

My dilemma is, do I continue using it as Net Beans designed it with PHPUnit-Skeleton-Generator and @assert notation, or do I just manually write my tests based on the documentation on PHPUnit's website?

I know most will say to use the PHPUnit docs, and I can't say I disagree. However, I want to still see the results in Net Beans GUI per their documentation. If I ditch the Skeleton and manually write my tesets, will I still be able to use the Net Beans integration to run and utilize the tests?

If I must still use the Skeleton to be able to use the Net Bean integration, is there a good resource to learn  how to use the skeleton? Are there other types of @asserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely can just write your tests and run them via NetBeans gui and watch results in it as well. Just don't forget to configure you testing preferences and options in Project properties => Testing => PHPUnit

[image]

If you don't need any special settings you can just choose to run all *Test.php files in testing directory (shown at screenshot).